# Applying Master Page to Team Site

Tags: 2013, master-page, branding, custom-masterpage, team-sites

I'm trying to apply a custom master page to a site collection based on a team site layout. I turned on `publishing infrastructure feature` on site collection level as well as `publishing feature` on site level.

However, publishing features don't seem to work. Although I can select the custom master page in the design manager, the site layout is not applying. Also the publishing tab on the ribbon is not showing up on the sites.

Is there any issue with the publishing feature (may I do any settings in CA), or are custom master pages on team site not possible in general?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to enable the publishing features at least per site level. You can access the Site Master Page Settings with `https://company/site/_layouts/15/changesitemasterpage.aspx` URL (i.e. add `/_layouts/15/changesitemasterpage.aspx` to the site's URL). Do you have your custom master page activated there?

Comment: I resolved the issue by setting the system master page to my custom master page (option: all channels). However, it doesn't seem to be possible just to change the standard master page and leave the system master page alone.
B.t.w. you are right, it isn't necessary to activate publishing features per site level. Thank you for that.